# LIBSVM svmpredict: why is testLabel needed for?

Tags: matlab, svm, probability, libsvm

I am new both matlab and libsvm. I have bag of words for 8 different objects size of 8*1000. I have trained each of them like this:

```
buildingStruct = libsvm_svmtrain(bow,[1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0],'-b 1')
```

After that, I wanted to test it by bow(1,:) which is training data for buildingStruct. ie:

```
[predict_label, accuracy, prob_values] = libsvm_svmpredict(testLabel, bow(1,:), buildingStruct, '-b  1');
```

In this sense; I do not understand what I supposed to give testLabel. And also if I make testLabel 1 for example, I got prob_values has size 5. Why it is 5 and why are they not close to 100 since i test the train data? Also accuracy is sth like [0;9;NaN]. What does that mean?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the order of parameters so that it becomes like that:

```
buildingStruct = libsvm_svmtrain([1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0],bow,'-b 1')
```

Then it will give you 1.00 prob as result. If you do not know test labels, just give random number as parameter.
For accuracy:  is a vector including accuracy (for classification), mean
squared error, and squared correlation coefficient (for regression).